# Exception Management

Tags: java, exception

If I call a method that call another method that throws an exception, but this is a IndexOutOfBoundsException, I have to throws this exception in every method that I need to use, or can I just throw it in the first method and the call it at the end.

Can I do this?:

```
 public static void b() {
    a();
}

public static void a() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        b();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iEx) {
        //Manage exception
    }
}
```

I wan't to use the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as a checked Exception because I`m reading a .ini file to get an array with some data that  I need in order to give them later to a datasource (BoneCp), to manage my connections. If the .ini does not contains the information required at the moment there is no way for me to know it, so I wan't to handle it in this way, (is no't a big application). However I also want to know what's the behavior with normal checked exceptions.

Comment: `b` should also declare it throws the `Exception`s or any other non `RuntimeException` declared by one of the methods used inside it at least that the exceptions are managed inside `b`.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException` so you don't need to declare it as thrown

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, it doesn't. `IndexOutOfBounds` is a `RuntimeException` and so `b()` doesn't have to declare anything in its signature.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I've edited my comment to clarify `b` should declare it throws any non `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I see it now. :)

Comment: According to the book "clean code" by Robert C. Martin, Exceptions should always be unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException) and you should write a wrapper exception that describes the error itself (ex. DatabaseUnreachableException instead of a method which throws 4 domain-specific exceptions which will force all using methods to throw or catch "internal" exceptions of the module). So in your case, the IndexOutOfBoundException should not be declared in the method signature due to it's a runtime exception.

Comment: Unfortunately I see no better way to hande my code, check my post again, I will provide some background on why I`m wanna use a RuntimeException as a checked exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexOutOfBounds` is a `RuntimeException`, which means that it is not a checked exception. So you don't need to declare it in the method signature, and I'd go so far as to say that you **shouldn't** (mention it in the Javadocs instead). Doing so makes it kind of ambiguous as to its checked/unchecked nature. Since the exception is unchecked, you don't need to declare it in the method signature for `b` either. However, if it was a checked exception you would have to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are relying on the wrong exception to make your program crash. If you are reading a file and you expect a certain content in it, you should make your application throw an error that explicitly mentions that. For example if you have a method that parses your file, you could catch the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception in there and throw a `new RuntimeException("some interesting message", e);` exception (where e is your IOOB exception). What kind of information does the IOOB exception alone give to your user?